# Gradio - launch has no progress

Tags: gradio

I have been launching a new page using Gradio (launch(share = True)), it has been working great. But today, I tried to relaunch the same app without changing any of my code, it is not working. The progress is stuck after the "Running on local URL:  [http://127.0.0.1:7864"](http://127.0.0.1:7864%22), no more message after that.The local URL works though.

Has anyone experienced this before? Any suggestions appreciated.

Thank you.